# Как найти длину строки в R?

Tags: r

Подскажите, как найти длину строки в R?

Answer (score 6):

```
> nchar("foo")
[1] 3
> set.seed(10)
> strn <- paste(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse = "")
> strn
[1] "NHKPBEFTLY"
> nchar(strn)
[1] 10
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134812/how-to-find-the-length-of-a-string-in-r

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stringr)
str_length("foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант @Yury Arrow лучше, с учетом такого, например, частного случая:

q <- NA
nchar(q) - результатом будет 2, а не NA, что должно бы получиться.

library(stringr)
str_length(q) - результатом будет NA.

Comment: R3.3.2 - nchar(NA) дает NA